# Weird character (:) in the Wordpress widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am not sure what title to give to this topic, so i apologize.

I am having WP blog running customized theme, and i installed Wordpress Popular Post Plugin.
It works as it should, but just after the link, it displays weird character that shouldnt be there ":".
It looks like this:

```
<a href="#"class="wpp-post-title" target="_self">Post Title Link</a>
:
<span class="wpp-excerpt">WThis is post excrpt bla bla</span>
```

I really dont have any idea why it is showing there.If anybody have any suggestion/advice, i would be very grateful.
This is the [link](http://lustrelife.com/news/), Top Section in the right sidebar

Comment: Eh... so edit the plugin template to look like you want it too?

Comment: That was the first thing i did, but i cant find any errors in plugin code: http://pastebin.com/H6LzNkAU

Comment: Yes,  you can edit the plugin template, but, first, you should see if the plugin let's you use a child theme template page so you can define your own view. The child theme will always keep your custom code when the plugin or theme is upgraded. You should also look to see if your plugin functions can be extended our overridden through your functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is in row 1140 of the plugin file.

`$excerpt = ": <span class=\"wpp-excerpt\">" . $excerpt . "</span>";`

Just remove the colon and you're done.